# Type mismatch when splitting range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

When I split a cell individually it works.

```vb
Public Function SplitTest()
    Dim colA, colB, colC
    Dim splitt() As String
    splitt = Split(Range("A1").Value, " - ")
    MsgBox (splitt(0) & " " & splitt(1) & " " & splitt(2))
End Function
```

When I try to split a range of cells I get a type mismatch error.

```vb
Public Function SplitTest()
    Dim colA, colB, colC
    Dim splitt() As String
    splitt = Split(Range("A1:A10000").Value, " - ")
    MsgBox (splitt(0) & " " & splitt(1) & " " & splitt(2))
End Function
```

Edit

```vb
Sub RightClickOpView()
    Dim varArr() As Variant
    Dim rCell As Integer
    Dim splitt() As String
    varArr = Range("A4:A10000")
  
    For rCell = 1 To UBound(varArr)
        splitt = Split(Range(varArr).Value, " - ")
        MsgBox (splitt(0) & " " & splitt(1) & " " & splitt(2))
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A1:A10000").Value` is a 2D array, which you can't call `Split` on.

Comment: You cannot split a whole range at once.  You will need to loop the range and do the individual.  I would recommend, loading the range into a variant array and looping that instead.

Comment: `splitt = Split(varArr(rCell, 1), " - ")`

Comment: if you wanted to display a list of arrays in the msgbox, how would you go about doing that?